# Has anyone managed to find level maps of Super Mario Bros.: The Lost Levels that include the checkpoints?

Tags: super-mario-bros-the-lost-levels

For a project I am trying to see where the checkpoint areas are in Super Mario Bros.: The Lost Levels which are invisible, and I can't seem to find a map that includes them so far. Any help?